# Nothing happened when running the code

Tags: excel, vba

I get nothing from this statement and I'm very new to VBA in Excel. Please help me understand why.

```
Sub Import()

Dim i As Integer

For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1

   If sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value > 99 And sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value < 10000 Then
   sheet1.Range("A" & i).Copy
   Sheet2.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial

   End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you beforehand

Comment: You can't do `Then ... And ...`.

Comment: ^ that too - i didnt even see that...

Comment: @DougCoats I'll add to your answer :)

Comment: it is always most helpful if you *tell us* what error you're having, otherwise we have to guess, or ask you for it, and since you *already know*, it's a waste of time if you don't provide that information up front...

Comment: It simply says syntax error. It points to the if statement if that's any help

Comment: @GregoryEaton put `Then` on the same line as the `If` statement.

Comment: @DavidZemens That apparently worked. Thanks.

Comment: See the documentation on how to properly construct your statements :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx

Comment: @GregoryEaton do consider marking Doug's answer as "Accepted"...

Comment: I changed the question @DavidZemens, but I figured out the answer on my own anyway. Since the answer to my original question was in the comments I'll mark this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
 Dim sheet1 As sheet1
```

should be

```
 Dim sheet1 as Worksheet
```

Same goes with sheet2 :)

You'll also need to *assign* something to these objects, otherwise you'll get an Object Required error, so for example:

```
Set sheet1 = Worksheets("your sheet name") 
Set sheet2 = Worksheets("some other sheet name")
```

Also: You can't do `Then ... And ...`.

`And` is a logical operator that's used for boolean expressions. It's doesn't join two expressions inside an `If` block. Instead, do this:

```
If sheet1.Cells(i, 1).value > 99 And sheet1.Cells(i, 1).value < 10000 Then
    sheet1.Range("A" & i).Copy 
    sheet2.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial

End If
```

Comment: Technically `sheet1` and `sheet2` don't need to be `dim`ed, assuming those are valid worksheet codenames, you can refer to them directly :)

Comment: Oh ok. I made the changes and I still get a syntax error

Comment: @GregoryEaton see the most recent revision to Doug's answer. You haven't assigned your Worksheet variables to any object.

Comment: @DavidZemens I simply removed their variable reference all together. The names are already sheet1 and sheet2

Comment: @DavidZemens I didnt know you could directly refer to sheets like that? Cool, i learned something today :D